# Swift 2: How to parse a time signature from MIDIMetaEvent?

Tags: swift, swift2, coremidi

Before Swift, a MIDIMetaEvent's data was accessed via data[0], data[1], etc.
To get to a time signature I need two values from the data part which is labeled as (UInt8)... with the parens.
But when I try to get the value in this way:

```
let midiMessage = UnsafePointer<MIDIMetaEvent>(eventData).memory
let data1 = midiMessage.data[0]
```

This results in an error: `"Cannot subscript a value of type 'UInt8' with an index of type 'Int'`

Any clue what I've done wrong here? Just getting `midiMessage.data` only returns the first byte of data.

Comment: In case it helps anyone figure this out, in the struct for MIDIMetaEvent, data is set as `data: (UInt8)`. From other posts the best I can ascertain is that it is a tuple. But if that is so, putting `data.0` and `data.1` should call different values? That is not working for me, either.

Answer (score 0):

No snark intended, but file a Radar and ask for an "enhancement" to get rid of using tuples for dynamically sized arrays. They have done this already with some parts of Core MIDI, but not meta events. Or MIDI thru.

It would be nice if they just added the Core MIDI functionality to AVFoundation (they've started) to get rid of the C API altogether.

In the meantime you can go through contortions like this which uses Mirror https://github.com/jverkoey/swift-midi/blob/master/LUMI/CoreMIDI/MIDIPacket%2BSequenceType.swift